# jQuery mobile dropdownlist doesn't hides with http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js

Tags: jquery-mobile

Got this ddl and it works fine with this version of jQm "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js":
But if I change it to 1.2.0 the items never hides. Anyone seen this problem?

```
                <asp:DropDownList ID="LanguageDropDownList" OnSelectedIndexChanged="LanguageDropDownList_OnSelectedIndexChanged"
                data-native-menu="false" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile and asp.net web forms fundamentally don't work together. The postback model and jQuery Mobile's ajax form loading and navigation are incompatible. Move to MVC or turn off ajax.

Make sure to invoke this code before jQuery Mobile initializes. (Include it before the  tag that references jQuery Mobile.)

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
      $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    });
</script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Comment: Didn't work. Is it your opinion that it doesn't work with web forms? And why shouldn't I use ajax with webforms? I know it's better with MVC but it isn't me that build the "app". I will proberly rebuild it to MVC someday but dont got time now :)

Comment: jqm with ajax relies on postbacks within `<div data-role="page">` regions with each region having its own `<form>` element. Web forms only allows for a single form which encompasses all markup. These two divergent approaches break jqm with ajax. You will never get it to work with web forms without turning off ajax loading.